# How to Set Background Color of Viewport

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, bitmap

I'd like to use a specific color for the background of a Viewport control in my app page (#2B2B2B).

```
<ViewportControl
    x:Name="Viewport"
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
    SizeChanged="Viewport_SizeChanged">
    <Image
        x:Name="Image"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        CacheMode="BitmapCache"
        ManipulationStarted="Viewport_ManipulationStarted"
        ManipulationDelta="Viewport_ManipulationDelta"
        ManipulationCompleted="Viewport_ManipulationCompleted">
    </Image>
</ViewportControl>
```

Adding `Background="#2B2B2B"` within `ViewportControl` has no effect.
My requirement is to create a bitmap of the Viewport containing the image, and since the image usually doesn't cover the entire Viewport I'd like to have a soft dark background behind the image.

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)Viewport.ActualWidth, (int)Viewport.ActualHeight);
wb.Render(Viewport, null);
wb.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Well, background is a valid property according to the docs, maybe try adding the alpha channel to your color? Like `Background="#FF2B2B2B"` Or just put something behind the image you know you can color, like a `Rectangle` or a `Background`

Comment: Alright so, adding the alpha channel in the Background of the Viewport had no effect, and neither did placing the Image control in a Grid, within the Viewport, and setting the Grid's background to the color.

Comment: Ya figured the alpha thing was 50/50, and the Grid thing I think would have to be <grid><rectangle fill="red"/><viewportcontrol/></grid> for it to work....except realistically the background property should work and I havent found any kind of template for it.

Comment: Agreed. What I did in the mean time was change the background of the LayoutRoot, and toggle the visibility of one control to achieve the same effect. I will keep researching though and post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Viewport in a stackpanel and give color to the background color to the stackpanel and if color is also covering the image use Zindex .